# Recover Sql Data From History Log file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I accidentally deleted the database, and I have an old backup with the same structure and old data; also I still have the new database history transaction log file. How can I restore my data from new log file?

Comment: What do you mean by the data base history log file? ِDo you have Transaction Log Files?

Comment: @M. Rezaeyan Yes

Comment: see https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/06/28/recover-lost-data-using-transaction-log-files/

Comment: if you have "trn" file, see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/111/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-transaction-log-backup/

Comment: When you mention Transaction log files, do you mean the .ldf file (ldf = log, mdf = data, ndf = also data)? Or do you mean transaction log backups? Unless you have transaction log backups, and a full database backup that goes together with that set of transaction log backups (and the set needs to be an unbroken chain), you'll basically just have the full backup.